# stolen Galaxy tab 4. can it be located

Tags: samsung

My Galaxy tab 4 has been stolen, it has a password on it but I know this is possible to bypass by factory reset. If the person has done this is it possible to still locate. Has it got an internal serial number which maybe Samsung could locate.

Comment: Have you tried to locate/lock using [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)?

Answer (score 1):

If the device has been factory reset, you won't be able to locate it using Android Device Manager. You could try asking Samsung but I doubt they can do this, especially on a device without data.